# ResponsiveSlides.js freezes on Opera Mini data saving on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, opera

I'm looking at: http://responsiveslides.com/ and the gallery freezes after 1/2 a transition, occasionally, it'll make one full transition and then freeze.

Turning the data savings off or tweaking it to a less aggressive setting like Turbo, the gallery works, but I'd like to know if anyone has had a good experience with "Opera Mini" data savings with ResponsiveSlides.js and how they got it to work?

I'm using Opera (8.0.2.80660) on iOS and visiting this site: http://responsiveslides.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Given that Opera Mini is a thin client that displays a static version of what's rendered on the server, it's impossible to get it to auto-page between different images in the slideshow.

I'd use the auto:false and pager:true setting: then the slideshow works fine in Opera Mini.